# Why is this algorithm for bracket balancing wrong?

Tags: php

I wrote a PHP function that counts whether a string contains the right numbers of pairs of brackets. I tested it and it works properly, but the website I'm answering says that this is wrong. Help me debug why?

```
function bracketBalancer ($string) {
  for ($i=0; $i<strlen($string); $i++) {
    if ($string[$i] == '(') {
      $parentheses++;
    } elseif ($string[$i] == '{') {
        $curly++;
    } elseif ($string[$i] == '[') {
        $square++;
    } elseif ($string[$i] == ')') {
        $parentheses--;
    } elseif ($string[$i] == '}') {
        $curly--;
    } elseif ($string[$i] == ']') {
        $square--;
    }
  }
  if (!$parentheses && !$curly
      && !$square) {
     return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: If it works properly, it is correct. Programming always has hundreds of ways to do the same thing. Some are better, some are worse - but don't sit there thinking you are wrong just because some website tells you that. If it works, it works. As you get more experience, you will find yourself coding things differently (hopefully improving as you go) and that's all there is to it.

Comment: Just a hint: If you compare a variable against a multitude of values, a `switch` statement most of the time is better for readability.

Comment: Just a thought, your answer would not detect invalid  nesting. i.e. [(xxx]).

Comment: `$string = '})][({';`

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I would have probably used some of the built in string functions to do comparisons with like this:

```
function bracketBalancer ($string)
{
    $ret=true;
    if(substr_count($string, '(') != substr_count($string, ')'))
    {
        echo "Parentheses don't match...\r\n";
        $ret=false;
    }
    if(substr_count($string, '{') != substr_count($string, '}'))
    {
        echo "Curlies don't match...\r\n";
        $ret=false;
    }
    if(substr_count($string, '[') != substr_count($string, ']'))
    {
        echo "Squares don't match...\r\n";
        $ret=false;
    }
    return $ret;
}
```

But as I said, there are a hundred ways to write code that does the same thing.

And on that note, looking at the code, it's bloody horrible, so here is a somewhat cleaner function:

```
<?php 
    function bracketBalancer ($string)
    {
        $match=array(
            'Parentheses' => array('(', ')'), 
            'Squares' => array('[', ']'),
            'Curlies' => array('{', '}')
             );
        $ret=true;
        foreach($match as $key=>$val)
        {
            if(substr_count($string, $val[0]) != substr_count($string, $val[1]))
            {
                echo $key." don't match.\r\n";
                $ret=false;
            }
        }
        return $ret;
    }

    $string='[{][)}[[}}[][))(())';
    echo (bracketBalancer($string))?"Everything matches nicely. Yay!":"Oh noes, there isn't matches!";
?>
```

We have an array that matches left and right brackets of sorts (or anything else for that matter) and a foreach statement that does the comparison for each pair spitting out the name of problem bracket/thing and returning a fail.

Output:

```
Parentheses don't match.
Squares don't match.
Curlies don't match.
Oh noes, there isn't matches!
```

Answer (score 0):

Your answer would not detect if the brackets are nested properly `[(])` or if they occur in the correct sequence `)(`. The following should work:

```
function bracketBalancer ($string) {
  $brkt = [];
  for ($i=0; $i<strlen($string); $i++) {
    if ($string[$i] == '(') {
      array_push($brkt, '(');
    } elseif ($string[$i] == '{') {
      array_push($brkt, '{');
    } elseif ($string[$i] == '[') {
      array_push($brkt, '[');
    } elseif ($string[$i] == ')') {
      if (empty($brkt)) {return false;}
      $c = array_pop($brkt);
      if ($c != '(') {return false;}
    } elseif ($string[$i] == '}') {
      if (empty($brkt)) {return false;}
      $c = array_pop($brkt);
      if ($c != '{') {return false;}
    } elseif ($string[$i] == ']') {
      if (empty($brkt)) {return false;}
      $c = array_pop($brkt);
      if ($c != '[') {return false;}
    }
  }
  if (empty($brkt)) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```